# Content is pushing sidebar down, and vice versa. css & html

Tags: html, css

im trying to get my sidebar to line up with my content, so they wont push each other down.

```
#website {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    background: #822;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#content {
    background-color: #862;
    width: 75%;
    height: 482px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

---

```
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    background-color: #5c5c3d;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 91%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#sidebar p {
    margin-top:0.3em;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
} 

#sidebar h1 {
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
}

#sidebar .shoutbox {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    background: #fff;
}    `
```

---

my html :

http://pastebin.com/zjEWF8Rs

Would love some help with this, tried fixing it for a long time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is a little messy. Try this:

**Content:**
    float: left;

**Footer**
    clear: both;

Reading tip: http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/

Comment: That pushed content under my sidebar, in other words, that did not work

Comment: That did the job, i appreciate the quick help!

Comment: Cool :) Please select as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to your `#content` rules.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrusbz8L/)